'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command in kubernetes node pool Windows2022
Trying to deploy windows pods in azure Kubernetes services using below docker file.
Docker file build is successful in azure DevOps pipeline and pushed to ACR, from there it is used to deploy the pods in the node pool
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2022

RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\" #Tried adding the path but did not worked, same issue, build was success but when deployed gave the error

RUN powershell -Command Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; `
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; `
    iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin"

# Install Nuget package provider
RUN powershell -Command "Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force -Scope AllUsers"

# Install Sql Server PS module
RUN powershell -Command "Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Force -Scope AllUsers"
RUN Setx /M PATH "\"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin";$env:PATH\""

WORKDIR /azp/

COPY ./start.ps1 ./

CMD powershell .\start.ps1

Error in the pod logs

Node Pool config for reference

Want to remove the error "'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command" and make the pods running
Edit
Explaining my workflow

Build the docker file and push in Azure ACR (which i can do without any issues)


Use the Image to create window pods in Azure Kubernetes cluster, where i am getting the error for powershell (attached above)



Workaround
Using image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 now and kubernetes node pool Windows2019. Rest code is same and its working for me.

The .NET Framework SDK image from mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2022 does not include PowerShell. PowerShell needs to be installed separately.

if that's the case then how the build of the Dockerfile was successful? Also the powershell doing all the installation as instructed

command that was successful
az acr build --image devops/windows:v0.0.5 --registry registryName--platform windows .

You can answer your own questions, it saves people from reading the comments and lets everyone know your problem is solved. Also easier for anyone else looking for the solution.

Faraz is your issue resolved? I didn't understand your comment- "command was successful." Is the issue resolved? If not then I was suggesting that  you can try adding the following line to your Dockerfile before running any PowerShell commands:
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"] This sets the default shell to PowerShell and sets the error and progress preferences.

@JeremyThompson its not solved, i am pointing out the anomaly that even though the build of the docker file is successful, the windows pods in azure kubernetes is given me the error "powershell is not recognized as internal or external command"

@Arko the problem is not with the docker build, build is a success, but when i deploy the same image (result of the build) i am getting this error

@JeremyThompson and Arko I have updated my question where i mentioned more in detail

The base image you're using (mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2022) should include PowerShell. However, sometimes, different base images may have different configurations for PowerShell. Try running the base image alone in AKS to check if PowerShell is recognized.

@FarazAhmad It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue with a workaround. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.

@NaveenSharma thanks for the advice, i have added the workaround as the answer

Found a workaround, degrading the versions by using the image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 and kubernetes node pool Windows2019. Rest of the script will be the same.
I am still not sure why the error occurred for windowsservercore-ltsc2022 and Windows2022.
